# How to get exact chance of three variables?

Tags: java, math, distribution

I am struggling to calculate the estimated chance of user to get an item. He have got 15 tries(which may vary), chance to get into group of items and then chance to get exact item. I can see two ways of doing it, but none is perfect. Please take a look:

```
    int userTries = 15;//Variable holding number of how many tries user has to get an item
    double groupChance = 17;//Chance for user to get any item from the group
    double itemChance = 80;//Chance for user to get specific item from the group

    double simpleChance = groupChance * itemChance * userTries / 100.0;

    int correctionTries = 10000;
    int totalPassed = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i < correctionTries;i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0;x < userTries;x++)
        {
            //Rnd.chance is checking if input chance was rolled, if chance is 17 then this method will return true in 17 tries out of 100
            if (Rnd.chance(groupChance))
                if (Rnd.chance(itemChance))
                {
                    totalPassed++;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    double iterationChance = (double) totalPassed / (double) correctionTries * 100.0;
    System.out.println("simple=" + simpleChance + " iteration=" + iterationChance);
```

When groupChance and itemChance are low(like 1 & 1), then simpleChance gives very good results, but when chances are high(like 17 & 80) then they vary a lot from iteration result. The problem with iteration solution is that when one I increase one of the chances, result actually be lower because of bad luck in calculated chances. I could increase correctionTries to solve that issue, but chance will be different when calculating same values once again and it also would have significant impact to performance.

Do you know any way to calculate that chance with low performance impact and good estimation that stays the same after calculating it once again?

Comment: Your description is unclear. What are `groupChance` and `itemChance`? If as their names suggest they are probabilities, why can they have values like 17 and 80? What does `Rnd.chance` do?

Comment: You need to clarify the number of possible items.  Once you do that it's a simple application of permutations and/or combinations.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog groupChance and itemChance are numbers between 0 and 100. They can be any of those numbers, 17 and 80 was an example. Rnd.chance is calculating random number between 0 and 100 based on nano time.

Comment: @duffymo could you please tell me what do you mean by number of possible items? groupChance & itemChance can be any number between 0 & 100, userTries can be any number between 1 & 2 bilions.

Comment: Yes but what do they *mean*? Are they the number of groups and items? You should include this information in your question instead of making the reader decipher it.

Comment: I am sorry, I have edited the question with description of the variables

Comment: You appear to be saying that there are 100 possible items: 0 to 100 exclusive.  A user can select 3 at a time.  You don't say if repetition is allowed or if order matters.  Once you figure it out you can find the formula here: https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Comment: Knowing the number of possibilities is key to calculating the probability.

Comment: User have got 15(which can be any number) tries to get any reward. Chance to get any reward is wrote as groupChance which is 17%(can be any number between 0 and 100). During that 15 tries when user will meet 17% requirement, then he can get any of the items from the group. Chance to get specific item is 80%(wrote as itemChance, it can be between 0 and 100). If user will get that item then the calculation is stopped(wrote as break in the code). So my question in other words is what is the chance for user to get specific item when he have got 15 tries & two chances which are 17% and 80%.

Comment: You don't understand what I'm asking.  No point in continuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **assume** that the `groupChance` and `itemChance` are probabilities (in percent) to get into the specific group and to get *the* specific item in the group..

If so, then the probability to get *this* specific Item is `groupChance/100 * itemChance/100 = 0.17*0.8 = 0.136 = 13.6%`

not clear either what `simpleChance` should be => to get *the* specific item at least once after 15 tries?? exactly once after 15 tries?? to get it 15 times in a row?

- if you want to get it 15 times in a row, then the chance is `(groupChance/100 * itemChance/100 ) ^ userTries = 0.000000000000101`
- if you want to get it at least once after 15 tries, then the chance is `1 - ( 1 - groupChance/100 * itemChance/100 ) ^ userTries = 0.88839`

Comment: Thank you "1 - ( 1 - groupChance/100 * itemChance/100 ) ^ userTrie" is perfect for me